# C# BinaryWriter length prefix - UTF7 encoding

Tags: c#

I've got a project using memory mapped files to let two apps share data with each other.
The producer app is written in C#, the consumer app talks plain old C. Both use VS2010.

MSDN says the "BinaryWriter.Write Method(String)" prepends the data with a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes the payload. This is exactly where I'm stuck. If I write
a string which is 256 characters in length, the debugger of the C app shows me this byte sequence: 0x80 0x2 <256 times the payload char>. What's the best way to convert the length prefix to something that I can safely use in the consumer app?

Producer app:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf_read = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("mappedview", 4096))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf_read.CreateViewStream())
            {
                string str;
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

                str = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("x", 256));

                writer.Write(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer app:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 4096
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\mappedview");


int _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCSTR pBuf;

    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,         // read/write access
               FALSE,                       // do not inherit the name
               szName);                     // name of mapping object

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
         GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    pBuf = (LPCSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,     // handle to map object
           FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,             // read/write permission
           0,
           0,
           BUF_SIZE);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
                GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Proc1: %s\n\n", pBuf);              // print mapped data

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

br,
Chris

Comment: `0x80 0x02` is the unsigned integer...

Comment: Yeah, almost forgot ;) If <= 127 bytes are written, the length prefix is exactly the first byte with that value. Else, the first two bytes seem to indicate the payload length, but I cannot figure out how to use them - please see the explaining text in my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite what the Microsoft documentation says,

1. The prefix number written is in fact an [LEB128 encoded count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128).
2. This is a byte count, *not* a character count.

The Wiki page I linked gives you decoding code, but I would consider using my own scheme. You could convert the string to UTF8 manually using [`Encoding.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) and write that to the MMF, prefixing it with a normal unsigned short. That way you have complete control over everything.

Comment: I will do as you suggested and make up my own byte/char/whatever counting function and use that as my prefix. Regards, Chris

Answer (score 10):

While the [MSDN Documentation on BinaryWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx) states it “first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer”, it is wrong. First of all, UTF-7 is a *string encoding*, you cannot encode *integers* using UTF-7. What the documentation *means* (and the code *does*) is that it writes the length using variable-length 7-bit encoding, sometimes known as [LEB128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128). In your specific case, the data bytes `80 02` mean the following:

> `1000 0000  0000 0010`
>
> `Nbbb bbbb  Eaaa aaaa`

- `N` set to one means this is not the final byte
- `E` set to zero means this is the final byte
- `aaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbb` are the real data; the result is therefore:

> `00000100000000`
>
> `aaaaaaabbbbbbb`

I.e. `100000000` in binary, which is 256 in decimal.

Comment: Matthew was a bit faster.Thanks for the thorough explanation !